# Java print string and int on same line

Tags: java

I was trying to print a string and int on a same line. But I get an error. I know my way around this error but why does the line `System.out.println("This is a string: %i", c2.a);`gives error whereas the line `System.out.println("This is class method" + c2.a );` gives the correct output. Below is my code.

```
public class MyClass
{
  private int a;
  public double b;

  public MyClass(int first, double second)
  {
    this.a = first;
    this.b = second;
  }

  // new method
  public static void incrementBoth(MyClass c1) {
    c1.a = c1.a + 1;
    c1.b = c1.b + 1.0;
  }

  //pass by valuye therefore no change
  public static void incrementA(int a)
  {
    a = a+1;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    MyClass c1 = new MyClass(10, 20.5);
    MyClass c2 = new MyClass(10, 31.5);
    // different code below
    incrementBoth(c2);
    incrementA(c1.a);
    System.out.println("This is a object passing: %i",c2.a);
    System.out.println("This is object passing: " + c2.a );
    System.out.println("This is pass by value: %d",c1.a);
  }
}
```

My other question is does the line `incrementBoth(c2)` changes value of c2 because here whole object is passed to the method rather than passing by value in `incrementA(c1.a)`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). - please ask one question at a time only.

Comment: Because println() accepts a single argument, not two. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-java.lang.String-. The error message tells you exactly that. You should read it. printf() takes several arguments: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-. So, in short, read error messages, and read the javadoc.

Comment: Regarding your second question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value?rq=1 would be a good read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the `printf` method and not `println`.

`println` is used to print primitive types, Strings and objects as they are. Also, println takes only one argument as input. That is the reason you are getting an error when you pass multiple arguments to it in your code.

`printf` on the other hand is used to format and then print the formatted string to the Standard output / error. This is what you should use in your code above for formatting the output.

Here's a [reference to the tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html).

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: This gives me an `Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = 'i'`. and no output is given. Why is that so?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

Comment: You need to use  `%d` not `%i`. Like this:    `System.out.println("This is a object passing: %d",c2.a);`

Comment: thanks @fuv would read it. But does my question really deserves -1. It strange to see that .

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
int x = 3;
System.out.println("This is my number" + x);
```

The output should be:

```
This is my number 3
```